# How to duplicate fields from base class c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the child class I need to duplicate fields from the base class. A simple example: if we have a base class `Car`, I want to make a car called `DoubleCar` which represents two cars in one (has two engines, 8 wheels, etc). This `DoubleCar` will act like a car (we can start it, speed up, brake, etc.) so it seems natural to make an inheritance. I try to do it in the following way

```
class Engine{
  public: void Start(){}
};
class Car
{
    Engine* engine;
public:
    Car(Engine* engine){this->engine=engine;}
    virtual void Start(){engine->Start();}
};
```

And create `DoubleCar` which has the first car from base class and a `secondCar` as field:

```
class DoubleCar : public Car
{
    Car* secondCar;
public:
    DoubleCar(Engine* e1, Engine* e2) : Car(e1)
    {secondCar = new Car(e2);}
    virtual void Start(){Car::Start(); secondCar->Start();}
};
```

This solution looks ugly, it seems like one car is more important than the other. I also tried to put both cars in fields and ignore base members, like this

```
class DoubleCar1 : public Car
{
    Car *firstCar, *secondCar;
public:
    DoubleCar1(Engine* e1, Engine* e2) : Car(NULL)
    {firstCar = new Car(e1); secondCar = new Car(e2);}
    virtual void Start(){firstCar->Start(); secondCar->Start();}
};
```

which also does not look as a good solution. What would be a good design for such problem? Of course, in my real problem, I have few parents of `Car` and several children, so I am in the middle of a hierarhy tree.

Comment: `so it seems natural to make an inheritance` Seems like you jumped to that conclusion pretty quickly :/ Particularly since you then go on to use half-inheritance, then pretend inheritance!

Comment: `DoubleCar` should have same functions as `Car`, this is why I make this conclusion.

Comment: @petar please for the sake of your code use [`std::shared_ptr`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of handling raw pointers yourself

Comment: @Petar: A 100m sprint would also have a `Start()` member function; that doesn't mean it _must_ inherit from `Car`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But if they share all function (probably 10,20 func), I guess I should use inheritance. I write this for simplicity with one function `Start()`.

Comment: @Petar: Then perhaps a `Vehicle` class to inherit, but not a `Car`. You can see right here in your question that it doesn't fit.

Comment: @Petar reading through this question it seems you have a domain language problem. Try figuring out your [Ubiquitous Language](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html) first and the entity map will come into focus.

Comment: Ask yourself what an instance of `Car` represents. Does it represent a unique `Car`? Multiple `Cars`? With a bit of common sense you'll figure out it should not represent both. When you inherit from `Car`, it should not turn into `MultipleCars`, otherwise you'd be infringing your design by ignoring the answer to the previous question. If `Car` and `MultipleCars` are going to share common properties (characteristics) and methods (behaviours), then you might want to create a new base type to meet both's requisites.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that a "double car" is about as "car"-like as a lorry, and that your attempts to forcibly inject an inheritance relationship is just messing up your conceptual model.

For example, your "double car" does *not* contain two cars. It contains twice as many engines and twice as many wheels as a normal car does, but it does not contain two cars.

I'd lose the relationship to `Car` entirely, and just focus on composing those reusable component types (such as `Engine`):

```
/** Has "car" in the name, but isn't a car. Cars are single-engined. */
class DoubleCar
{
    Engine e1, e2;

public:
    virtual void Start() { e1.Start(); e2.Start(); }
};
```

If you're desperate for a shared interface, I'd go no further than the "vehicle" level, providing a pure virtual `Start` and whatever else you have.

Answer (score 1):

Generally inheritance models "is a" relationships. Often this is going from generalized base classes to more specific derived classes. For example: A car is a vehicle. A Ford Mustang is a car. So to model that you might end up with a base class of Vehicle, then a derived class of Car, and then a further derived class of FordMustang.

Now if we tried to say "a double-car is a car", that sounds a bit weird. It's not just one car. It's two.

If we were to say that "a double-car is composed of two cars", that sounds reasonable. So one might end up with a DoubleCar class have two Car members. That's closer to your last idea, but wouldn't be derived from Car.

At this point, if I were writing the code, I would start questioning my design in general. Is there actually any reason for DoubleCar to inherit from Car? "Having the same member functions" isn't enough. Will you ever need to feed a DoubleCar through an interface that takes a Car reference or pointer? If not, then maybe it shouldn't be derived from Car at all. In that case, the composition idea works and DoubleCar is essentially a kind of Car container.

But without knowing more about the specifics of the situation you're actually working with, I'm not sure I can give any better ideas.